# How to animate view from code behind on embedded view button click

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have `ContentPage` named `MainPage.xaml` with `MainPageViewModel` set.

`MainPage` has following content view

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:myViews= ...>

  //this view has a button with 'Handle_Click'
  <myViews.View1 ... />

  <BoxView x:Name="boxView" .../>
</ContentPage>
```

`View1` has `View1.xaml.cs` and has `Handle_Click` event as bellow

```
void Handle_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // How to access 'boxView' in this file so that I can animate.
   // I can only access 'boxView' in respective MainPage.xaml.cs
   // if I cannot access it over here , then how to let MainPage.xaml.cs know to animate
}
```

I am doing animation in code behind because I believe animation is part of UI and hence needs to be done in code behind and not in VM. Also I cannot access `boxview` in VM by name to animate.

Please correct me in my approach.

Comment: View1 needs to expose a public event to the parent page, and then the parent can animate the BoxView.  View1 shouldn't directly interact with the BoxView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason mentioned, since `boxView` belongs to `MainPage` it's better to handle it animation in MainPage's code-behind, for that you need to expose a public event handler of `View1`, subscribe to it in `MainPage` code-behind, and invoke it from view1 code-behind:

MainPage.xaml

```
  <myViews.View1 x:Name="view1" />
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            view1.Clicked += View1_Clicked;
        }

        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            view1.Clicked -= View1_Clicked;
        }

void View1_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// animate boxview
}
```

View1.xaml.cs

```
public event EventHandler Clicked;

void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    //checking null before invoking 
    Clicked?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, . If someone has MainPage as ContentView and not ContentPage then OnAppearing() / OnDisappearing() will not be available and OnBindingContextChanged() with a null check for BindingContext can be used instead.